# mysql - selecting from result

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin

I have a table

```
scores(user, score)
```

and I have this query

```
SET @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score 
FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC
```

now I want to select, from this query result, the user with name 'john' and score '1400' to know what is his row_index, something like

```
SELECT row_index 
FROM *result* WHERE user='john' AND score=1400
```

how do I do that? I tried

```
SET @row_num = 0; 
SELECT row_index 
FROM (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score 
      FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC)      
WHERE user='john' AND score=1400`
```

but phpMyAdmin says

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

How can I do that?

Thank you,
Alessandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added an alias to the derived table.

```
SELECT row_index FROM (...) AS alias
WHERE alias.user = 'john' AND alias.score = 1400
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot, i think it is the quickest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Query:

```
SET @row_num = 0; 
SELECT a.row_index 
FROM (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, 
             user, 
             score 
             FROM scores ) a
WHERE a.user='john' AND a.score=1400
ORDER BY a.score DESC
```

I think Ordering in Subquery not always allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

```
SET @row_num = 0; 
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC;
SELECT row_index FROM v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @row_num = 0; 

SELECT row_index FROM (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, 
score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC) AS alias1 WHERE user='john' AND score=1400
```